# getAllByRole and then getByText combined

Tags: react-testing-library

How can I combine two RTL screen methods?

I have several H4s on my page, with different text inside. I wish to a) return back all h4s and then b) return a specific one by text

- I want to retain the check that it was a heading
- I want to retain the check that the heading was of level h4
- I want to pull back a specific h4 based on its text

I do not want to just dive right into the text using `getByText` but test both parts:

`const myHeading = screen.getAllByRole('heading', { level: 4 }).getByText("my heading text")`

I know I can write a `find` function to return the element inside the array returned by `getAllByRole` to find the one with `children` equalling my text. But it seems quite messy. Is there an easier way to combine two RTL queries?

I tried using `within` however it seems `within` is designed for a page section not an array, so it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have usually accessed heading text through the `name` option.  Perhaps this could work in your case?

i.e.

```js
screen.getByRole("heading", {level: 4, name: "text in the heading"})
```